# Avoid Return "input" Automatically in Struts

Tags: struts2, struts-config, struts-validation

There is no problem when the action configuration in struts.xml is like this:

```xml
<action name="customer-form">
    <result name="success" type="tiles">/customer.tiles</result>
</action>
```

The problem comes when I access the action class on action configuration (struts.xml). I access the class before displaying the form because I want the dropdown option in the form to display the appropriate value as I instantiate it in action class. But it turns out, it will return "input" and I must handle it.

**method in action class:**

```java
public String addCusto(){
    custoType = new ArrayList<String>();
    custoType.add("ABC");
    custoType.add("EFG");
    System.out.println(custoType.size());
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

**struts.xml:**

```xml
<action name="customer-form" class="com.satunol.struts.template.action.CustomerAction" method="addCusto">
    <result name="success" type="tiles">/customer.tiles</result>
    <result name="input" type="tiles">/customer.tiles</result>
</action>
```

**form in jsp**

```
<s:form action="savecusto" method="post" validate="true">
<s:select
   label="Customer Type"
   list="custoType"
   emptyOption="true"
   headerKey="-1"
   headerValue="None"/>
<s:textfield name="custo.name" key="custo.name" size="20" />
<s:textfield name="custo.email" key="email" size="20" />
<s:textfield name="custo.address" key="address" size="20" />
<s:textfield name="custo.phone" key="phone" size="20" />
<s:submit method="addCustomer" key="label.add.customer" align="center" />
```

The result? The `addCusto` method is not executed, and my form is directly/automatically validated although not yet submitted.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Is it typo the two `success` results?

Comment: @MahadiSiregar Can you post your Jsp code and explain more what you want to achieve?

Comment: I have put it. I want the dropdown (select) to display list option according to value that I have set in action class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Action can return an `input` result, then you must handle it in the struts.xml configuration.

`input` result is returned by the Validation Interceptor when some validation error occurs, or when you are trying to set the wrong *type* of an Action's properties, for example when you try to set a `int` to a `Date` field.

When an Interceptor is returning a result instead of proceeding to the next Interceptor (or the Action if it is the last), the Action method called won't be executed, because it won't be reached.

Check out carefully your code and your request to see where it is failing and returning the `input` result.

P.S:

If with

> I access the class before displaying the form because I want the dropdown option in the form to display the appropriate value as I instantiate it in action class.

you mean that you need to prepopulate fields before the execution of any method (or when `input` result is returned), you should use `prepare()` method for that, run by the Prepare Interceptor that runs before the Validation Interceptor. That way, your `prepare()` code will be executed even when validation will fail.

For more info, read [How do we repopulate controls when validation fails](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/how-do-we-repopulate-controls-when-validation-fails.html)

Comment: It solve when I add <interceptor-ref name="prepare"/> to action configuration in struts.xml. 
Whether that is the right way?

Comment: Yes, but it is in the Default Interceptor Stack by default... if your stack wasn't running it, it was because you created a custom Interceptor Stack without it. Just use the default, or remember to include the Prepare Interceptor in the custom stacks you create.

Comment: Yes, I create default custom interceptor without including it into default. Thank you, it solve my problem.