# Struts2 validation doesn't work only with regex

Tags: java, regex, jsp, validation, struts2

The validation works fine with the required string (and email, I tested just these). But when I try to use regex, the validation has no effect.

```
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "-//Apache Struts//XWork Validator 1.0.3//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-1.0.3.dtd">
<validators>
    <field name="cognome">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <param name="trim">true</param>
            <message>Cognome è un campo obbligatorio</message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>
    <field name="telefono">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <message key="errors.required" />
        </field-validator>
        <field-validator type="regex">
            <param name="expression">[0-9]{9,15}</param>
            <message>Il numero di telefono deve essere minimo di 9 cifre
            </message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>

</validators>
```

*telefono* must have between 9 and 15 numeric digits. This give error when the fields are missing, and no error if I insert a *telefono* like "123".

the jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html;"
     import="java.util.*,it.almaviva.bean.*,it.almaviva.delegate.*;"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/stile1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>Registrazione account</title>
</head>

<body>
<jsp:include page="header.jsp"/> 
<s:actionerror />

<s:form name="formDatiUtente" action="inviaRichiesta.action" method="post" theme="simple" validate="true">

<center>
<s:fielderror></s:fielderror>
<table width="48%" class="LISTA" border="0" cellPadding="3" cellSpacing="5" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td width="35%">
                        <p class="testodx">
                            <s:text name="label.cognome" />
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p class="testosx">
                            <s:textfield name="cognome" id="idCognome"
                            size="30" value="%{anagraficaVDR.cognome}" />
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p class="testodx"><s:text name="label.telefono_Ufficio_reparto" /></p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <s:textfield name="telefono" id="idTelefono_Ufficio_reparto" size="30" value="%{anagraficaVDR.telefono}"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>

</table>
<br>

<s:if test="!gestioneAmministratore">
    <s:submit method="execute" cssClass="bottone" key="label.invia" align="center" />
</s:if>    
</center>  

</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

another secondary problem is that if I remove this:

```
<s:fielderror></s:fielderror>
```

the error messages are not displayed. That it's strange, because for example [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/struts2-validation-framework-tutorial-example/) this string is missing and the error messages are showed correctly (each under every field, thing that I prefer).

Another secondary problem is that if I doesn't insert a field and I press submit, I get (correctly) an error, but all the values in the fields are erased, instead I prefer to keep all (like in the previous example that [I linked](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/struts2-validation-framework-tutorial-example/)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parameter should be `regexExpression`, not `expression`.

http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/regex-validator.html

To display a specific field's error, use the `fieldName` attribute, e.g.,

```
<s:fielderror fieldName="cogname" />
```

Note that `<s:form>`'s `validate` attribute regards client-side validation; it has nothing to do with validation on the server side.

Comment: Thanks, this works!
And about the other secondary problem? How do I show every message errors near the correspondent field? If I remove <s:fielderror></s:fielderror> the error's feedback is lost.

Answer (score 2):

For the secondary problem (but it should be another question, imho), the reason is that you need to put a fielderror with the name of the field under the field itself.

When using certain Struts Themes, like the default one, it's handled automatically.

Since you are probably using Simple Theme, then you need to do it yourself (also note that you should use label instead of paragraphs):

```
<label for="idCognome">
    <s:text name="label.cognome" />
</label>

<s:textfield name="cognome" id="idCognome" value="%{anagraficaVDR.cognome}" />

<s:fielderror fieldName="cognome"/>
```

The field will be rendered only in case a fielderror named "cognome" will be found.

Comment: Yes, maybe 3 questions should be better... and about the other? Why if do I get an error all fields are erased? How can I prevent this?

Comment: because you are using another source (anagraficaVDR) for the value of your objects, [and that source is not loaded yet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17186258/1654265). Then use prepare() or something similar.

Comment: Doesn't exist another alternative way instead of prepare()? I should copy the data somewhere and after copy them in the prepare(), it's quite long...

Comment: Fare domande multiple è il tuo tallone da killer ? :) Aprine una nuova e posta il codice (interessato) della action...

Comment: I hope the god of code would forgive me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22045493/struts2-validation-repopulate-all-the-fields-when-validation-fails