# Why struts.xml is correct, but the page is 404?

Tags: java, validation, struts2, actionresult, struts-action

Struts version is 2.3.16

In `struts.xml`, I added this

```
<action name="ajaxuser" class="com.pp.ajax.UserAccount">
    <result name="success">/out.jsp</result>
</action>
```

the xml and the `UserAccount` class are correct, because some request to this url is OK, but some request is 404.

This is the successful request

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/pp/ajaxuser
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate
Accept-Language:zh-TW,zh;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:45
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:JSESSIONID=B6D15A95251B1477473BC524E7E9E148; Siggraph-Fontresizer=105; targetEncodinghttp://your-site=1; PHPSESSID=k2fi36gbn8979riffibp2mt1f7; _ga=GA1.1.2049659497.1410967472
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/pp/user-account
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
userId:2
username:b
password:b
oper:edit
id:8
Response Headersview source
Content-Length:5
Content-Type:text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Date:Thu, 25 Sep 2014 07:09:26 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

---

And this is the failed request

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8080
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/pp/ajaxuser
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 Not Found
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate
Accept-Language:zh-TW,zh;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:55
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:JSESSIONID=B6D15A95251B1477473BC524E7E9E148; Siggraph-Fontresizer=105; targetEncodinghttp://your-site=1; PHPSESSID=k2fi36gbn8979riffibp2mt1f7; _ga=GA1.1.2049659497.1410967472
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/pp/user-account
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
userId:abc
username:abc
password:abc
oper:add
id:_empty
Response Headersview source
Content-Language:en
Content-Length:1089
Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 25 Sep 2014 07:10:15 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

I cannot see any different between these two request, so I don't understand why this problem occurred

I also added a breakpoint at the begin of `UserAccount`, but the program cannot reach this breakpoint, and server show this error

```
WARNING: Could not find action or result: /pp/ajaxuser
No result defined for action com.pp.ajax.UserAccount and result input
```

I have no idea how to trace this problem, what can I do now?

Comment: I defined the action and result in struts.xml, and it is correct, but I still get this error.

Comment: There is no **input** result in your configuration.

Comment: Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25682007/1654265).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing POST request and the validation interceptor might return `INPUT` result. Usually you can fix it with adding an `INPUT` result to the action configuration.

```
<action name="ajaxuser" class="com.pp.ajax.UserAccount">
    <result name="success">/out.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">/out.jsp</result>
</action>
```

you can also exclude this action from validation by removing [`validation` interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/validation-interceptor.html) from the action config or adding method to the interceptor config parameter `excludeMethods` by overriding it, then you don't need this result.