# How to validate Dropdown in Struts2

Tags: java, validation, struts2, struts-action, interceptorstack

I am writing an action class in which I want to print errors using `Struts2`. In my JSP page I got a drop down and I have 10 states in it. When I deploy the application the field error for `Null` always shows up without even clicking any button. I want that error to be printed in case if a user doesn't select any state from the dropdown.

**Action Class:**

```
public String modifyState() {
        CatastropheDataTO catDataTo = new CatastropheDataTO();

        try {
            catDataTo.setState(this.state);
            catDataTo.setActive(Boolean.valueOf(this.active));
            catDataTo.setStartDate(this.startDate);

            if( getState() != null ||  getActive() != null || getStartDate() != null ) {
                getCatastropheManager().updateCatastropheData(catDataTo);
                addActionMessage(this.getErrorMessageFactory().generateMessage(Constants.ERROR_CODE_7).getMessageText());

            } else if(getState() == null){
                addFieldError("state", "Please select a state");
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            addActionError(this.getErrorMessageFactory().generateMessage(Constants.ERROR_CODE_3028).getMessageText());
        }
        return SUBMIT;
    }
```

Somehow the `getState()` is always null due to which `"Please select a state"` always show up, while I want this to be printed if a user directly clicks on the submit button without selecting any state.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use two actions ([that can be two methods of the same Java class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35779105/1654265)), the first one to render the page, the second one to perform the business that should be executed after pressing the button.

In your case:

```
public String showStates() {
    return SUCCESS;
}

public String modifyState() {
    CatastropheDataTO catDataTo = new CatastropheDataTO();

    try {
        catDataTo.setState(this.state);
        catDataTo.setActive(Boolean.valueOf(this.active));
        catDataTo.setStartDate(this.startDate);

        if( getState() != null ||  getActive() != null || getStartDate() != null ) {
            getCatastropheManager().updateCatastropheData(catDataTo);
            addActionMessage(this.getErrorMessageFactory().generateMessage(Constants.ERROR_CODE_7).getMessageText());

        } else if(getState() == null){
            addFieldError("state", "Please select a state");
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        addActionError(this.getErrorMessageFactory().generateMessage(Constants.ERROR_CODE_3028).getMessageText());
    }
    return SUBMIT;
}
```

That said, your approach is bypassing the mechanisms of the framework, that provide you several inbuilt methods to perform the validation (`validate()`, `XML`, `annotations`...).

The most similar to the one you're using is the `validate()` method that (to prevent the previously explained problem to arise again, can be applied to some method only, instead that to all the action methods of the class, with `validateXXX()` or `@SkipValidation`.

The result would be something like:

```
@SkipValidation
public String showStates() { // call this the first time
    return SUCCESS; // or INPUT, or whatever
}

public void validate(){
    if(getState() == null){
        addFieldError("state", "Please select a state");
    }
}

public String modifyState() {
    CatastropheDataTO catDataTo = new CatastropheDataTO();

    try {
        catDataTo.setState(this.state);
        catDataTo.setActive(Boolean.valueOf(this.active));
        catDataTo.setStartDate(this.startDate);

        if( getActive() != null || getStartDate() != null ) {
            getCatastropheManager().updateCatastropheData(catDataTo);
            addActionMessage(this.getErrorMessageFactory().generateMessage(Constants.ERROR_CODE_7).getMessageText());

        } 

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        addActionError(this.getErrorMessageFactory().generateMessage(Constants.ERROR_CODE_3028).getMessageText());
    }
    return SUBMIT;
}
```

Comment: @Yousuf, do you mind upvoting the answer (if you like it) and accepting it (if it worked) ? Thank you

Comment: I see you've never upvoted nor accepted an answer after 11 questions :| Is there a reason behind that ? To upvote, press the up arrow in the top left corner of the answer; to accept, press the white V turning it to green. http://stackoverflow.com/tour