# how to call a particular method of action of Struts2 through jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, struts2, struts-action

I am new to jquery and ajax. I want to call a particular method "logout" of action 'LoginAction' in Struts2. I am getting an error

> There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name logoutLoginAction.

My ajax code is:

```
function signout(){
     $.ajax({   
         type: "POST",
         assync:false,
         url: "logoutLoginAction.action",
         success: function(messageResponse) {                   
         response=messageResponse;
         alert(response);
     }});        
}
```

Comment: Do you have `logoutLoginAction` action in your configuration? You can create one if you don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is called [Wildcard mapping](https://struts.apache.org/docs/wildcard-mappings.html).

In your case it should be something like:

```xml
<action name="/*LoginAction" class="foo.bar.LoginAction" method="{1}">
    <result>{1}.jsp</result>
</action>
```

If you will call `logoutLoginAction`, logout will be used as `{1}` and then the `logout()` method will be called and the `logout.jsp` file will be returned.

Alternatively, you can define an action for every method of your Java file, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35779105/1654265).

Comment: Thnks, your answer helped to clarify my doubt.