# Struts 2 Fields Validation with dynamic forms

Tags: jsp, validation, struts2, struts-tags, repopulation

I have Struts 2 application.

I have a jsp file which looks like below

```xml
<s:form method="post" action="%{#attr.actionType}">

    <c:forEach items="${nvpList2}" var="item">
        <s:textfield label="%{#attr.item.displayName}" 
                     value="%{#attr.item.value}" 
                      name="%{#attr.item.getName()}" 
                        id="%{#attr.item.getName()}"/>
    </c:forEach>

    <s:submit type="button"   cssClass="btn btn-primary" 
               key="button.save" theme="simple" >
        <i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i>
    </s:submit>

</s:form>
```

As it can be seen  that all the elements starting from action name to field names are created dynamically

Problem occurs when I do a validation check on fields.
On validation check, the errors are shown but none of the textfields appear in the page.

How do I solve this problem.

Comment: Errors are shown when you return input result, so before the result listener can repopulate the list.

Answer (score 2):

Read the detailed workflow of [what happens when a validation or conversion error occours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23450365/1654265);

Once you get what is happening, read [How do we repopulate controls when validation fails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17186258/1654265) (`prepare()` method and other ways);

Then, take a look at which kind of notation (and structures, in complex cases) you need to build to [send Lists or Maps from JSP to Action](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15009137/1654265), no matter if static (JSP or HTML) or dynamic (JSP [or Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15267703/1654265));

Finally, I'm not sure why you are using JSTL instead of [a Struts Iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19516627/1654265), nor I know the data structure you are sending data to, but pay attention to the need of putting an index in the name (with `IteratorStatus.index`).